# Python string comparison acting funny

Tags: python, string, comparison

this is weird:

```
def separatewordsbycaps(word):
    """This custom template will add space to fields when it finds a capital letter.
    Ex. InstrumentDeployment --> Instrument Deployment"""

    wordList = list(word)

    spaceIndexes = [index for index, char in enumerate(wordList) if char.isupper() and index!=0]
    offset = 0
    space = "f"
    for idx, val in enumerate(spaceIndexes):
        print "1."+wordList[val+offset-1]+"!=" + space +"= " + str(wordList[idx+offset-1] != space)
        print type(wordList[val+offset-1])
        print type(space)
        if wordList[idx+offset-1] != space:
            wordList.insert(val+offset, space)
            offset += 1

    return ''.join(wordList)

print separatewordsbycaps("InstrumentfOutputfVariables")
```

Output:

```
1.f!=f= True
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
1.f!=f= True
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
InstrumentffOutputffVariables
```

I search the interweb for help, maybe there's something wrong with my code. Please help.

Comment: *this is weird* .... What is weird? What else are you expecting? What is so *funny* in this?

Comment: You use `val` in one place, `idx` in the other.

Comment: Style nitpick: consider using `words_with_underscores` for function and instance names.

Comment: Alright, that's the error. Thanks interweb friends. Val was the right variable to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing what you think you are comparing.

You print:

```
wordList[val+offset-1] != 'f'
```

but you actually are comparing:

```
wordList[idx+offset-1] != 'f'
```

Note the difference between `idx` and `val` there.

For your input, the first `val` is `11` and `idx` is `0`, so you are printing `wordList[val+offset-1]` which is indeed `'f'` and thus equaly to the value in `space`, but you are actually comparing against `wordList[idx+offset-1]` which is `'s'`. `'s' != 'f'` is indeed `True`.